# How to get pandas dataframe as a series?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, statsmodels

I am trying out the `statsmodels` library of python.I have a data that has certain `trend` and `seasonality`.`statsmodels` provides a way to plot these trends and also get the coordinates as a dataframe.This is my code below

```
df = pd.read_csv("test_forecast/upload_data.csv")
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"], format="%Y-%m-%d")
df.set_index("date", inplace=True)
df = df.resample('D').mean().interpolate(method='linear', axis=0).fillna(0)
```

Now I try to get the coordinates for say `trend`.

```
print(sm.tsa.seasonal_decompose(df["upload"]).trend.interpolate(method='linear', axis=0).fillna(0))
```

Here is the output

```
date
2018-04-22     3.919738
2018-04-23     3.985145
2018-04-24     3.839589
2018-04-25     3.723810
2018-04-26     3.566047
2018-04-27     3.416895
2018-04-28     3.215901
...            ...
...            ...
```

Now I want the output in the form of a list.So I execute the code with `.values`

```
print(sm.tsa.seasonal_decompose(df["upload"]).trend.interpolate(method='linear', axis=0).fillna(0).values)
```

I get the output as below

```
[3.91973791  3.98514482  3.83958857  3.72381001  3.56604662
  3.41689526  3.21590053  3.21826295  3.17641971  3.25942285  3.39823427
  3.51068301  3.80029493  4.17883987  4.40204831]
```

But I also want the `date` values as well such that my output would be something like

```
[['2018-04-22', 3.919738], ['2018-04-23', 3.985145], ['2018-04-24', 3.839589]].....
```

How to get the `date` as well in an array along with the values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try,

```
 df.reset_index().values.tolist()
```

Comment: What if the dataframe has more than one column?

Comment: you need to slice the df with the required columns

Answer (score 0):

In addition to `@pyd`'s answer, the complete answer to get the required output (without `reindexing` and using `tolist()`) is

```
coordinates = list(map(list, zip(df.index.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), sm.tsa.seasonal_decompose(df["upload"]).trend.interpolate(method='linear', axis=0).fillna(0).values)))
```